# I stupidly turned on OBJC Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). Now my code is messed up. Can I undo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appcelerator

I code in Javascript using the Appcelerator framework.

This AM I decided to open Xcode and turn on ARC based on some online advice.

Well it seems Xcode refactored all my original JS files into something I cannot understand or read.

This project has been something I've been working on for years.   My last backup is from 6 months ago, so going back to that one is a very very painful option.

Is there any way to 'undo' the refactoring and bring back my original files.  Either in Xcode, OS X or any kind of way.  I'll do anything at this point, since I'm suicidal now and stepping outside to get some fresh air and relax :)

Thank you for any advice!!!!!  I'll give away all my points to help fix this :)

Comment: This is what source control is for.  Xcode usually asks you if you want to take a snapshot before doing any refactor/conversion so if you said yes to that you should be able to restore it.

Comment: @dan it did not ask me about snapshots.  I just clicked on 'restore snapshot' and it says Unable to read snapshots ;(

Comment: There's the undo key (command-z), you might try that. changing the project to arc shouldn't mess it up that bad; what all is wrong exactly?

Comment: Do you use Time Machine on your computer or any source control (e.g. git)?

Comment: Last backup is from 6 months ago?! Omg! You seriously need to dive into source control. You've got quite a problem atm. Are you using disk encryption? If not, you can try some software to read previous version, but you should not override anything in that area i'm afraid. Hard case.